# How to make the borders to the details section in a Jasper report run till the end of the page?

Tags: formatting, jasper-reports

I was making a report using JasperReports.

If you see the image below, the details section of the report does reach the end of the page if there is no sufficient data.

[image: Details section of the report]

How can I make it reach the end of the page?

If I need to post the JRXML code, please let me know I'll post it.

Thank you.

Comment: We need same thing: borders around whole A4 page. I posted `background band` workaround, unfortunately it does not work with docx format: docx ignores background. Are there any way to do this without `background` band?

Answer (score 0):

draw a vertical line in `background` band with height equal to max height of page `detail` section